# Create list of class instances satisfying some condition on their attribute(s) value(s)

Tags: python, oop, list, iteration, agent-based-modeling

How can I create a sublist of class instances satisfying some condition on their attribute values, starting from the complete list of class instances?

For example, I have a list of instances of my class Person(). These persons have many attributes, among which ID, a unique identifier, and HH_ID, the identifier of the household they live in.
I want to connect all the persons living in the same household, and therefore having the same HH_ID. By "connect", I mean creating an edge between all the household members, using `networkx`.
In order to do this, I need to identify these persons and put them in a "sublist", in order to be processed by some algorithm to connect them all together. How can I achieve this?

I need also a general tool to do this for other more complex purposes (e.g. randomly connect N persons aged from 15 to 20 year), but in the easiest case of household members, I can use the fact that my list is ordered by ID and HH_ID, therefore I have something like:

```
ID HH_ID
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  1
5  2
```

where the first household is composed of persons [0,1,2], the second of persons [3,4] and so on...

For this household problem I have tried using the `pairwise` iterator recipe ([itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) in this way:

```
import pairwise
i = pairwise(personList)
for p in personList:
    toConnectList = [p]
    p1,p2 = i.next()
    while p1.hh_id == p2_hh_id
        toConnectList.append(p2)
        p1,p2 = i.next()
        # connect all persons in toConnectList
```

But obviously this doesn't work, as my iterator `i` goes down until `hh_id` of the two adjacent persons don't match, and restarts from there for the next person. E.g. for the persons in the above example, my iterator will start to compare persons 2 and 3 when it comes to person 1 in the `for` loop, while I would need some way to jump directly to person 3 in the for loop and have my iterator start comparing person 3 and 4.
I hope this example clarifies a bit, even if it doesn't look very clear...

More generally, I need a way of creating a sublist of persons satisfying some conditions on their attribute values, possibly an efficient way (I have around 150000 persons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

def family_key(person):
    return person.HH_ID

persons.sort(key=family_key)
for hh_id, family in groupby(persons, key=family_key):
    for person in family:
        # do your thing
```

For more complex purposes, just alter the key function to return the same value for those items you want to group.

**EDIT:** Fixed error: `groupby` returns a tuple `(key, group_iter)`, not just `group_iter`.

Comment: Thanks, this groupby wasn't very clear at first, but it is exactly what I was looking for!